I editted shadings of the model, but exported model not reflects the changes
So, i got one fbx model with textures online and imported it to blender. But the alpha maps were weirdly connected to meshes, so i manually removed them and made some tweaks to shadings
i was satisfied with how the model looks, so i wanted to export the model in fbx so i could use it in UE5
But as i export the model in fbx in copy-texture embedded option, i found out that the exported model is not changed, the texture settings were all the same with the first one; all alpha maps connected
Gltf seems like it doesnt carry those settings but when i load the glb file, the base color map was weird like below
Am i doing something wrong when i export the model into fbx? I hope i could use some help



.fbx export why there are no materials or textures
